# Como cambiar la descripción de los permisos Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Quisiera saber cómo puedo cambiar la descripción de los permisos que crea Django automáticamente y listar solo los permisos que yo desee,
Tengo pensado que sería para mí mejor crear un modelo OtrosPremisos y agregarle automáticamente los que me hacen falta pero eso no lo sé hacer
Ejemplo:

'Class OtrosPremisos(Permissions):
     permiso=models.CarField()
     descripcion=models.CarField()'

Nota:Mi falta de conocimiento es cómo insertarle los permisos desde aquí mismo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te recomiendo crear otro modelo de permisos ya que la que gestiona Django es la que se genera automáticamente ,lo que te recomiendo es crear permisos nuevos en tus modelos , así puedes personalizar los permisos que desees.

A continuación te pongo un ejemplo de como crear un permiso desde un modelo, Se puede crear uno o varios luego este permiso se lo asignas al usuario que quieras desde admin

```
class NombreModelo(models.Model):
    ....
    ....

    class Meta:
        permissions = (('xyz_nombre_permiso', 'Descripcion del permiso'),
                       (.....),  )
```

vamos a suponer que he creado varios permisos con el prefijo `xyz`, y ahora voy filtrar los permisos en la vista que desee:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
permissions = Permission.objects.filter(codename__icontains="xyz_")
```

con esta consulta te devolverá todos los permisos que contenga el texto `"xyz_"` en el codename

Comment: yo pensé hacerlo así pero después como listo los permisos creados nadamás

Comment: puedes ponerles un prefijo a los permisos que crees y luego filtras con icontains

Comment: me podrías poner un ejemplo, en la respuesta que hiciste

Comment: te he modificado la respuesta, saludos